# get the data from data-src from each div and use that data on the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to take the `data-src` value from each `img` and then take that value and attach it to the `img` as `src=""` so my end result would look like this: `<img data-src="image1.jpg" src="image1.jpg">` I am writing the `data-src` into the `img` not the `src`  Here is a jsfiddle and the html and JS

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4s9m7nhq/

HTML:

```
<div class="slide-image">
    <a href=""><img data-src="image1.jpg"/></a>
</div>
<div class="slide-image">
    <a href=""><img data-src="image2.jpg"/></a>
</div>
<div class="slide-image">
    <a href=""><img data-src="image3.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you giving a div a src attr?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to take the data-src from the img tag and then add a src= the data-src and put that in the img tag not the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slide-image a img").each(function () {
        this.src = this.dataset.src;
    });
});
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4s9m7nhq/7/)**

Comment: I would recommend using `this.dataset.src` instead of `$(this).attr("data-src");`

Comment: @howderek why not `$(this).attr("data-src");` directly?

Comment: then you have to call jQuery and another function from the jQuery object. `this.dataset.src` uses the existing data that jQuery returned

Comment: I'm not saying your solution doesn't work, it does, it's just adding more steps than necessary.

Comment: here is jsperf proof that it is less efficient if you need it: http://jsperf.com/dataset-vs-attr

Answer (score 1):

Use the HTML5 `dataset` attribute of an element to get your `data-src` attribute

```
 $(".slide-image a img").each(function () {
     this.src = this.dataset.src;
 });
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/4s9m7nhq/16/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 $('.slide-image img').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('data-src'));
});
```

### Working Demo